What is the BGR+ wire supposed to do?
While trying to fix the vents of my 2080ti  (Zotac) I made some mistake.
Now there is a lose cable, basically 4 raw pins.
They seem to lead to a 4 pined part on the vents of my graphics card.
Directly under the pins, there are the letters BGR+.
I first thought, maybe its some lighting it would normaly be known as RGB, but since there is a + and the letters are cleary in this order, I am not so sure...
Can someone explain to me, what this cable is supposed to do or what the connection is used for?
Is this a lethal issue or can it be fixed? (In theory I could try to solder the contacts)
Does it even NEED to be fixed?
I did find some teardown videos, but since I am not that fit on the hardware side, I have no idea what the part that can be seen in the video at the end, where he is unplugging the loose wire (at about 5:05) , could be and what relevance it has.
here are some pictures of the connection that has broken:
[2


it is not totally clear what your problem is because the video shows a keyed white plastic connector which should make it easy to re-plug. However—while it is too small in the video to see clearly—it looks like the cable has blue and red wires plus 2 others.
I would assume that the text means Blue - Ground - Red + but you probably want to check for a better source, since it looks "nonstandard" for fan control.

I voted this down because you're doubting yourself in the answer, which basically means this should be a comment instead.

@LPChip: I think that's literally why it shouldn't be a comment?
